# sending a picture from my react native app to my laravel API with axios

Tags: laravel, react-native, axios

i want to send a picture from my react native app to my laravel backend , for that am retrieving the picture URI and send a picture object using axios with others string data but the post request fails . knowing that when i send a post request without a picture , everything works fine .

**EDIT :** i have commented all the code on the if statement of my laravel function and changed it to a simple affectation to my $picture variable :
$picture = "picture" , but the product is not added ! which means that the request is not even sended from my react app when i provide a picture .

my react native function :

```
    const config = { headers: { "Content-Type": "multipart/form-data" } };
    // appending some string data ...
    data.append("position", JSON.stringify(position));
    // checking if the user took a picture ..
    if (this.state.uri !== null) {
      let filename = this.state.uri.split("/").pop();
      data.append("picture", {
        uri: this.state.uri,
        name: filename,
        type: "image"
      });
    } else {
      data.append("picture", null);
    }
    // sending the request with axios to my backend ..
    const response = axios.post("product/create", data, config);
```

my laravel function :

```
   $user_id = $this->retrieveIdByToken($request->token);
    $picture = null;
    if ($request->hasFile("picture")){
        $picture = $request->file("picture")->getFilename() . "_" . $user_id . "." . $request->file("picture")->extension();
        Storage::putFileAs(
            '/public/products/pictures/', $request->file('picture'),$picture
        );
    }
    $product = Product::create([
        'user_id' => $user_id,
        'price' => $request->price,
        'position' => json_decode(json_encode($request->position)),
        'category_id' => $request->category_id,
        'name' => $request->name,
        'description' => $request->description,
        'caracteristics' => json_decode(json_encode($request->caracteristics)),
        'image' => $picture
        ]);
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

i found out the solution , first i do not need to give axios a configuration , and the second one is that the type most be image/jpeg

Answer (score 1):

Use RNFetchBlob library.

How it works,

Use Image Picker and save the image in state and then, use this code
10.0.3.2 is for genymotion, replace it if using real device

```
 RNFetchBlob.fetch('POST', 'http://10.0.3.2:8000/api/uploadImage', {
    Authorization : "Bearer access-token",
    otherHeader : "foo",
    'Content-Type' : 'multipart/form-data',
    'Accept':'application/json',
  }, [
     { name : 'image1', filename : 'avatar.png', data: this.state.image1},
    ]).then((response) => response.json())
  .then((responseJson) => {

    alert(JSON.stringify(responseJson));

  }).catch((err) => {
    alert(err)
  })
```

In Laravel,
YOUR API,

```
Route::post('upload','ReactController@save');
```

YOUR CONTROLLER

```
public function save(Request $req){
$destinationPath = public_path('/upload');
            $image1=$request->file('image1');
            $_image1 = rand().'.'.$image1->getClientOriginalExtension();
            $image1->move($destinationPath, $_image1);

$info = new Upload;
$info->image = $_image1;
$info->save();

return json_encode("Successfully Saved");
}
```

Comment: Hey usama , thanks for answering my question but i wrote the solution down , the problem was that the type most be **image/jpeg** and not **image**